# Create new telegram chat group using bot (aiogram, telebot...)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

How to make a function for telegram bot which create new unique group and send invite link to a user?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def cmd_test(message: Message):
    chat_id = "-100000000000"
    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date.timestamp, 1)

    print(link.invite_link)
```

Here I have chat with 'chat_id' which was created manually.

***MAIN QUESTION:*** How to generate new chats and invite links to them?